# How to change text size in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to building Web pages. Just for training, I made a really simple site but, I don't understand why I can't change text size.

If I delete background image code works, but I can't do that like this:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("h1, p").addClass("dark");
        $("div").addClass("important");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #grad1 {
      background-image: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg");
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

      p {
        font-size: 28px;
      }

      .important {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: xx-large;
      }

      .dark {
        color: dark;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="grad1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 align="center">Dzīves jēga</h1><br><br>
      <p align="center"><dfn>“Dzīves jēga nav gaidīt, kad beigsies
          negaiss..
          bet gan iemācīties dejot lietū!”</dfn></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg btn-info">Izmaiņas ir
        neizbēgamas</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I just cant figure this out siting here for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because you did not have the closing bracket for `#grad1` style.

Change style to -

```
#grad1 {
  background-image: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Here is the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7odvac3/3/)

Comment: @defs There is also no such CSS color as `color: dark`.

Comment: sometimes we miss them too.. :) Glad it was fixed.